# Filing matrix by bands

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I need to fill a matrix, `CSI`, by taking elements from an array, `inverse`, which is the Inverse Fast Fourier Transform of an array called `powerspectrum`.
The way the `CSI` matrix is filled is by creating "bands" according to the following Python code:

```
CSI = zeros((n, n))
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if abs(j-i) < (n/2):
            CSI[i][j] = inverse[abs(i-j)]
        else:
            CSI[i][j] = 0
```

where I first initialize the matrix `CSI` setting its values to 0 and then I fill the bands. I must do the same in Mathematica. How can I do that? Here is what I have tried so far, but it does not work:

```
inverse = InverseFourier[pts];
CSI = SparseArray[{For[j = 1, j < n/2 + 1, ++j,
                        Band[{1, j}] -> inverse[[Abs[i - j]]]]}, {n, n}]
```

Comment: Provide a minimal example *with data examples* for input and result. Readers should not have to infer such things, nor decode non-Mathematica code.

Comment: The CSI matrix could look something like this:

Comment: {
  {5.19697, 1.5303, 0, 0},
  {5.80303, 11.6667, 1.5303, 0},
  {0, 5.80303, 11.6667, 1.5303},
  {0, 0, 5.80303, 6.4697}}

Comment: Use `Table`, not `For`.

Comment: Your code produces a symmetric matrix (right?) but your example `CSI` is not symmetric.

Answer (score 3):

I post this in case it is of assistance:

```
func[mat_] := Module[{n = Length[mat], tup},
  tup = Cases[Tuples[Range[n], 2], {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] < (n - 1)/2];
  SparseArray[
   Thread[tup -> (mat[[Abs[#1 - #2] + 1]] & @@@ tup)], {n, n}]]
```

This produces sparse array for an array input (in your case "inverse") and I have tried to to take account Python arrays starting at 0.

As a test and perhaps to allow you to achieve your desired result:

```
tf[n_] := 
 With[{u = Range[n]}, 
  Row[{u // MatrixForm, "->", Normal@func[u] // MatrixForm}, 
   Frame -> True]]
Grid[Partition[tf /@ Range[3, 9], 2], Frame -> All]
```

I have done it this way so you can see what elements are chosen.

There are many ways to accomplish desired goal in *Mathematica*. Play and use of Wolfram resources and this site are invaluable.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming* *ubpdqn*'s *translation holds*, this should be a much faster route to the same result:

```
f = With[{n = Length@#}, ToeplitzMatrix[PadRight[Take[#, Floor[n/2]], n]]] &;
```

Quick perf. comparo of `Func`, using `Table`, and `f` (on loungebook):

[image]

Comment: very nice...always learning :)

Comment: @ubpdqn: Thank you, of course if our guess on result is wrong, for naught... and +1 back at you - nice presentation as always.

Comment: indeed...just was trying to facilitate either clarification or self-directed action...either way progress